# SetOptions not persistent between sessions

Tags: options

Let's say I decide I want all my axes to be colored red, so I do

```
SetOptions[Plot,AxesStyle->Red]
```

For the remainder of my session, I correctly get

```
Options[Plot,AxesStyle]
(* {AxesStyle->Red} *)
```

But when I quit and subsequently reload MMA, I get

```
Options[Plot,AxesStyle]
(* {AxesStyle -> {}} *)
```

For how long are changes made by `SetOptions` supposed to persist? I (apparently incorrectly) understood that these changes were supposed to persist across sessions (i.e., permanent). I thought if you wanted such changes to persist only for the current session, you needed to use something like `$FrontEndSession`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For how long are changes made by SetOptions supposed to persist?

Normally, `SetOptions` is used with functions (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html)). In this case changes do not persist across kernel restarts.

> I (apparently incorrectly) understood that these changes were supposed to persist across sessions (i.e., permanent).

No, that is not the case, except in special situations.

> I thought if you wanted such changes to persist only for the current session, you needed to use something like $FrontEndSession.

`SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ...]` does indeed persist between restarts. This is a special case though. The same applies to using `SetOptions` with cell or notebook references: the cells/notebooks are modified, and if you then save them, the changes become permanent.

This use of `SetOptions` in my mind is completely distinct from setting options for functions, it just happens to have the same syntax.

Comment: thank you very much. I suppose adding `SetOptions[symb,rule]` to a kernel Init.m file would make the change persist across sessions? Not sure if that's a best practice, but it seems it would work.

Comment: @bmclaurin Yes, it would work. I do not think it is best practice, and I do not recommend it. Sometimes people change stuff in their `init.m`, then forget it, and it takes a long time to figure out the cause of a problem they are posting about. If you want to change multiple such options, put the changes in a package, and load that package manually when you need it.

Comment: Perfect counsel, thank you again.